# How to pass blank array in ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am facing an issue where I am unable to pass blank array(if array is **null**) in Ajax Post request though array initialized in first step. Not empty array get passed in post request.

In below code, I have initialized **array** named **selectedDeliveryLocations**. When array is not empty

> (for eg. ["888888", "17", "5", "2", "3"])

variable selectedDeliveryLocations I received on ajax page but if it is empty, all I receive only city variable on Ajax request to which I should receive selectedDeliveryLocations variable as well with selectedDeliveryLocations **[]** blank array.

```
$("select[name='city']").on("change", function(){
var city = $(this).val();

var selectedDeliveryLocations = [];
if( $("select[name='service_locations[]']").val() != '' && $("select[name='service_locations[]']").val() != null){
    selectedDeliveryLocations = $("select[name='service_locations[]']").val();
}

$.ajax({
    url:"ajaxGetSelectedDeliveryLocOnCityChange.php",
    data:{
            city:city,
            selectedDeliveryLocations:selectedDeliveryLocations
        },
    type:"post",
    success: function(response){
        var response = JSON.parse(response);
        if(response){

            $("select[name='service_locations[]']").html(response.responseContent);
            $("select[name='service_locations[]']").selectpicker("refresh");

            showSelectedDeliveryLocations();
        }
    },
    error: function(){ alert("Something went wrong, please try again"); },
    complete: function(response){}
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`selectedDeliveryLocations = $("select[name='service_locations[]']").val() || '';`

and check accordingly on your server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no value selected in **service_locations**, then `selectedDeliveryLocations = $("select[name='service_locations[]']").val();` returns undefined or null.

You can pass a default value as an empty array to override falsey values like below

```
selectedDeliveryLocations = $("select[name='service_locations[]']").val() || [];
```